# jQuery TotemTicker issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ticker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#vertical-ticker').totemticker({
        row_height  :   '55px',
        next        :   '#ticker-next',
        previous    :   '#ticker-previous',
        stop        :   '#stop',
        start       :   '#start',
        direction   :   'up',
        });
    });
  </script>
```

We have a jQuery Totem Ticker in our rails app; we want it to scroll down instead of up. the plug-in's [homepage](http://buildinternet.com/project/totem/) says to add the following line:

```
direction   :   'up'
```

But this doesn't work. How should it be done?

Comment: I didn't think it would, necessarily (that's why it's added to the comment, not posted as an answer), but trailing commas often cause problems in scripts. Could you post a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo, or similar, so we can see what you're working with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The download on the [project page](http://buildinternet.com/project/totem/) seems to be outdated: there is no mention of `direction` in the code. Try the [github version](https://github.com/buildinternet/totem) instead, which seems to be checking for the `direction` setting.

Comment: To be fair in his original text he did refer to the 'GIT' page, (without a link) so I may have screwed up the edit when I amended that with the first result for 'totem ticker jquery'.

Comment: @David yeah, I saw that. I think he looked in the github page's documentation, but used the download link on the web site (which is a logical thing to do; the author should update his link.)

Comment: @Pekka the github version makes no mention of `direction`, we're javascript/jQuery rookies and evidently its showing here because were stumped.